# Eclipse Hangs when dealing with xml's (going to or from them). CPU + Disk spike at this time

Tags: xml, eclipse

I have to deal with many XML's on a daily basis. This is interrupting my work flow greatly; I've tried downgrading to Indigo but all my add-ons get removed.

The problem occurs when opening an xml; switching to an xml; switching out of an xml (even to another xml). What is happening that makes XML's so annoying? What can I disable, or change, to get better performance?

Restarting eclipse tends to help a bit, but not for long (an hour or so).

During these times my CPU spikes from a few % to 70-80% so whatever it is doing is very resource intensive.

I believe that there is correlation between these times and disk usage as well.

edit: To clarify, it's not just when switching from an xml to another xml, it's also when I change focus from the main xml to another frame, i.e. project explorer, problems, console.

Comment: did u fing solution for this??

Comment: As far as my experience goes, this happens when you install some EE plugins onto the same Eclipse as the Android plugin, and if to be more specific, this also happened to me after only installing the JavaScript plugin!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you are hitting a [known performance issue](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385272) with Juno and Juno SR1. The platform team is currently working on a number of performance bugs for SR2, some have already been fixed. I think downgrading to Indigo or Eclipse 3.8 are your only options. Some of the specific bugs related to XML editors:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391127

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=391868

Comment: Well that's bad news,  looks like the release for sr2 is in February of next year.  I guess downgrading is the best option,  thank you for your help

Comment: Actually the best option was replacing the default XML editor with another one

Answer (score 5):

I solved it!!!
(I've Eclipse Indigo)

1. Open ***yourWorkspaceFolder\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources*** folder
2. Delete "**.snap**" and "**.markers.snap**" files (I suggest backup them before)
3. Restart Eclipse

Comment: I have no such directories there

Answer (score 3):

I found a way around it. Took out the xml editor, replaced it with Rinzo XML (but I'm sure any other one would work, that was the first free one I saw), and everything is almost as fast as normal.

Comment: How to do it?? please explain and provide links if possible

Comment: how did u do it ? i want to know because i am also facing same problem ?

Comment: @AndroidKiller There's some instructions at the link RankWeis provided, specifically on: http://editorxml.sourceforge.net/download.html (the section on going to "Help > Install New Software")

Answer (score 2):

Did you try disabling all XML validations ?

`Windows -> Preferences`

[image: Disabling Validation in Eclipse]

Comment: Yeah, I've suspended all validation actually in the hopes it would do something but no dice. Thanks for your reply